# How to convert upload file type to graphql UploadFile type?

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, graphql, graphql-js

I try to upload image to server in my client side built with vue.js but I have an error all times.
I have tried to send request with formData, have tried with file list object directly, with file object.

But nothing seems works good.

#### My form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input
    @change="uploadPhoto($event)"
    accept="image/*"
    ref="file"
    type="file"
    name="files"
    id="files"
    class="inputfile inputfile-upload"
    capture="user"
  >
</form>
```

#### My upload function

```
uploadPhoto({ target }) {
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('files', target.files)

  HTTP.post('/graphql', {
    query: `
      mutation UploadFile($file: Upload!) {
        upload(file: $file) {
          id
          hash
          url
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      file: formData,
    },
  })
},
```

#### Displayed error:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"The \"path\" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type undefined"
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `graphql-upload` (previously `apollo-upload-server`) or `apollo-server` (which uses `graphql-upload` under the hood), you should be using a [client that supports the GraphQL Multipart specification](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec#client).

If you're using Vue, it's easiest to set up Apollo [utilizing the appropriate Link](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client).

Example usage:

```
const { ApolloClient } = require('apollo-client')
const { InMemoryCache } = require('apollo-cache-inmemory')
const { createUploadLink } = require('apollo-upload-client')

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: createUploadLink()
})
```

See the docs for additional details.